# tmux recognised Conda env but still use the default python

Tags: python, anaconda, tmux

I have trouble using anaconda environment in Tmux. I am on OSX.

I first

```
tmux
```

Then activate the Conda env:

```
conda activate myenv
```

At this point when I `conda info` shows the correct active environment and correct location. But `which python` still points to the default `/usr/bin/python`.

In the `.bash_profile` I have these lines added by anaconda when installed. So I guess I need to add something to let the terminal find the right python path?

```
# added by Anaconda3 5.3.1 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/jiajunyang/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/username/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/username/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
```

Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: have you added the anaconda interpreter to the PATH?

Comment: Also, were you trying to mask your user name, but only changed half of them? I.e., why are half `"/Users/username/anaconda3..."` and half `"/Users/jiajunyang/anaconda3..."`?

Comment: Possibly related to: https://superuser.com/a/583502/114468

Answer (score 20):

Below works for me on **macOS 10.15 with zsh**:

Add below line to your `~/.tmux.conf` file

```
set -g default-command "/bin/zsh"
```

If you're using a shell other than `zsh`, I assume changing the path to the shell you're using will also work.

Comment: What I found at the end is that tmux resort the path environment variables. So the default Python comes first instead. So the solution resource the path at /etc/profile.

Comment: This solved it for me, and I'm using a zsh from homebrew

Comment: One could also use `set -g default-command "$SHELL"` so it picks your current shell.

Answer (score 2):

same here, mac 10.14, tmux 3.0a
solution is:

```
  source /Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
  [[ -z $TMUX ]] ∨ conda deactivate; conda activate base
```

add 2 lines in your .zshrc. Then

```
  source ~/.zshrc
```

everything works fine now!!

Comment: Hi, I got ".zshrc:143: parse error near `∨'" here, Is the command correct?

Comment: @J_yang I got the same error.  So you have to run the command manually after entering tmux.  Once you are in tmux, run "conda deactivate" follow by "conda activate base"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Finally I find that tmux will always call the profile for your shell, not just the rc. So if you are using bash like I do, it will call /etc/profile, which will have a call to path_helper.

In order to fix this, change `/etc/profile` to:

```
if [[ -z $TMUX ]] && [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

If you are using bash, also change any `export PATH=$PATH:/foo` in `.bashrc` to

```
if [[ -z $TMUX ]]; then
  export PATH=$PATH:/foo
fi
```

then you restart the terminal(for example Iterm). Everything should be good!

Comment: This indeed work on OSX, saving my day!

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Basically @2015 penn got correct answer, but more robust way should clean all conda envs entirely:

```bash
# Add below lines at tail of your ~/.bashrc file
function conda_deactivate_all() {
    while [ -n "$CONDA_PREFIX" ]; do
        conda deactivate;
    done
}
[[ -z $TMUX ]] || conda_deactivate_all; conda activate base
```

### Reasons

The problem is due to the working mechanism of `conda.sh`, which locates the `condaPath` in your `$PATH` and update them in-place - however, when using TMUX, the homebrew will be loaded in a hard-encode way on top of `condaPATH`:

```
Original Bash
-> Activate Conda ENV
      {$PATH=condaPath:homebrewPath:sysPath}

TMUX
-> Load .bash_profile
      {$PATH=sysPath:condaPath:homebrewPath:sysPath}
-> Load .bashrc
   -> Pop Homebrew paths at top
          {$PATH=homebrewPath:sysPath:condaPath:homebrewPath:sysPath}
   -> Replace Conda paths in-place
          {$PATH=homebrewPath:sysPath:renewCondaPath:homebrewPath:sysPath}
```

Conda in-place update is for ease to use conda environments, but this update mechanism severely conflicts with TMUX. So we could add a `if` using TMUX, let's entirely re-init the conda!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to activate your env. ( replace the  with your env name)

```
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate <env-name>
```